# Redirecting takes place even to wrong urls

Tags: php, redirect

I have written a script, to redirect the users who visit my website,

```
http://localhost/ghi/red.php?go=http://www.google.com
```

When theres URL like above my script grabs the go variable value and checks whether its there on my database table as a trusted site if so it redirects to the site. In this occurance the redirection should take place even for sub domains

as an example even if the "go" variable has a value like www.google.com/images the redirection should take place if www.google.com is there in the trusted sites table.
I do that by using PHP INDEX OF function as below

```
$pos = strrpos($trusted_sites, $go_value);
```

this works fine, But there is a problem that i accidentally came across...

Which is even if the go variable has a value like www.google.comqwsdad it still redirects the user to www.google.com

this is a serious bug any help would be highly appreciated on how to avoid redirecting to wrong urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want such redirect from a whitelist of sites. First build of the whilelist in an array. Then you can compare them using `in_array()` from the `$_GET['go']`. Consider this example:

```
// sample: http://localhost/ghi/red.php?go=http://www.google.com/images

if(isset($_GET['go'])) {
    $go = $_GET['go'];
    $url = parse_url($go);
    $go = $url['host'];
    $scheme = $url['scheme'];
    $certified_sites = array('www.imdb.com', 'www.tomshardware.com', 'www.stackoverflow.com', 'www.tizag.com', 'www.google.com');
    if(in_array($go, $certified_sites)) {
        header("Location: $scheme://$go");
        exit;
    } else {
        // i will not redirect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" way is to us an array of sites (or even a database), then use in_array.

```
<?php

$trusted_sites=array("http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com");

if (in_array("http://www.google.com",$trusted_sites)) {
    print "Ok\n";
} else {
    print "Bad site\n";
}
```

A quick way of cheating, which I use from time to time, is to make sure you have a separator (e.g. a space) as the first and last character of your `$trusted_sites`, then add the separator to the beginning and end of your `$go_value`.

```
<?php

$trusted_sites="http://www.google.com http://www.yahoo.com";

$go="http://www.google.com";
if (strpos(" $trusted_sites "," $go ")===False) {
    print "Bad site\n";
} else {
    print "Ok\n";
}
```

In this example, I've added the separator (a space) to the beginning and end of both variables, inside the `strpos()`; in the case of `$trusted_sites`, I could have put them in the initial declaration instead.

Comment: but i want redirecting to take place when the go has a value like go=www.google.com/images but with this way it would not redirect to such values